# How to restore default Mountain Lion font distribution?

Tags: macos, bootcamp, font

[Deleting windows font which were copied from my bootcamp partition](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/59384/deleting-windows-font-which-were-copied-from-my-bootcamp-partition)

I'd like to clean the installed font list because there might be a lot to deactivate by hand.

Is there a way to confirm which fonts do not originate from a Mountain Lion default installation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starting in Lion, Apple added a `Restore Standard Fonts…` command to Font Book. Open Font Book and choose `File > Restore Standard Fonts…`:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there may not be a way to do it automatically, but [here is a list](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5379) of fonts that are included in Mountain Lion.

Also, once you get them all restored, you can use a font manager to help you organize your fonts. This will allow you to "group" your fonts, and install and uninstall whole groups in one step. Google "font manager mac", and you'll get some options.